# PostgreSQL installer crash up at startup

Tags: windows, postgresql

I downloaded postgresql-13.2-2-windows-x64.exe file and when I try to start up installation I see only logo for one second and this is end. I see this file in task manager as a background process, sometimes as a sub-process of Opera(thread I think). Maybe anyone can help me to fixed this problem.

Comment: try to run it in terminal and see if it reports any error message ,

Comment: Nothing. Just go to next line without any info.

Comment: i am facing same issue, did u find any solution

Comment: Yes. I have to remove Avast from my computer.